# BLE api converts negative temperature to positive

Tags: c++, arduino, floating-point, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to extract the temperature from a BLE beacon using the ESP32 chip. I have used the following code to do this:

```
class MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks: public BLEAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks {

void onResult(BLEAdvertisedDevice advertisedDevice) {
  std::string strServiceData = advertisedDevice.getServiceData();
  uint8_t cServiceData[100];
  strServiceData.copy((char *)cServiceData, strServiceData.length(), 0);

  if (advertisedDevice.getServiceDataUUID().equals(BLEUUID(beconUUID))==true) // found Eddystone UUID
  {  
    Serial.printf("Advertised Device: %s \n", advertisedDevice.toString().c_str());advertisedDevice.getServiceDataUUID().bitSize(), advertisedDevice.getServiceDataUUID().toString().c_str(),strServiceData.length());

    if (cServiceData[0]==0x20) 
    {
       BLEEddystoneTLM oBeacon = BLEEddystoneTLM();
       oBeacon.setData(strServiceData);
       Serial.printf("Eddystone Frame Type (Unencrypted Eddystone-TLM) \n");
       Serial.printf(oBeacon.toString().c_str());
    } 
    else 
    {
      
    }
   } 
  }
};

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);

 BLEDevice::init("");
 pBLEScan = BLEDevice::getScan(); //create new scan
 pBLEScan->setAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks(new MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks());
 pBLEScan->setActiveScan(true); //active scan uses more power, but get results faster
}

void loop() {
 BLEScanResults foundDevices = pBLEScan->start(scanTime);
 delay(5000);
}
```

The temperature output is fine for positive values however when the temperature goes to negative values I still get an unusual positive number.

Serial monitor output:

```
Advertised Device: Name: , Address: ac:23:3f:85:2e:f3, serviceUUID: 0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 
Eddystone Frame Type (Unencrypted Eddystone-TLM) 
Version 
art_cpu0_default mV
Temperature 241.0 °C
Adv. Count 3782
Time 0000.00:30:34
```

From the above debug message, this specific beacon should be reading -18 C and not 235.0 C. I know this because the android app that came with the BLE tag shows the temperature which was -18 C and I put the tag in a freezer which was set at -18 C.

Can anyone assist me on why I am getting a positive float value when it was suppose to be negative?

The library I am using can be found [here](https://github.com/nkolban/ESP32_BLE_Arduino/blob/master/src/BLEEddystoneTLM.cpp)

As per advice from a user I have noticed my issue is not with my code but rather the library. The code is too long to post however the link is provided above. The issue seems to be to the declaration of the m_eddystoneData.temp and casting of temp to an unsigned value. Hence the output will always be positive.

```
void BLEEddystoneTLM::setTemp(float temp) {
  m_eddystoneData.temp = (uint16_t)temp;
} // setTemp
```

Comment: ` -18 C and not 235.0 C` being about 256 about is suspicious.  Yet posted code lacks relevant temperature part.  Please post a [mcve] _here_.  Tip: text as text is better than text as pictures.

Comment: Can those users give me back my post now so I can answer it. I have provided the code, the library for reference and the output of the code and the issue I am facing. Not sure what more detail is needed...

Comment: Paul, there is no posted code _here_ that shows how "Temperature 241.0 °C" was derived.  The problem appears to exist in code not posted here.  Best to put needed info/code in the question and not require navigating off site to solve.  You still have the ability to improve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the library you linked to and it had the following for temperature:

```
void BLEEddystoneTLM::setTemp(float temp) {
    m_eddystoneData.temp = (uint16_t)temp;
} // setTemp
```

and

```
BLEEddystoneTLM::BLEEddystoneTLM() {
    beaconUUID = 0xFEAA;
    m_eddystoneData.frameType = EDDYSTONE_TLM_FRAME_TYPE;
    m_eddystoneData.version = 0;
    m_eddystoneData.volt = 3300; // 3300mV = 3.3V
    m_eddystoneData.temp = (uint16_t) ((float) 23.00);
    m_eddystoneData.advCount = 0;
    m_eddystoneData.tmil = 0;
} // BLEEddystoneTLM
```

Both appear to be defining the temperature to an unsigned short of 16-bits. I assume that they should be signed and hence `int16_t`

Comment: Well done looking and finding this

Comment: I have changed (uint16_t)temp to (int16_t)temp, but I still get the same problem. I changed it in the BLEEddystoneTLM.cpp file on my pc where it is making reference too

Comment: nevermind I solved it

Comment: Good news!  Looking forward to seeing what the issue was.

Comment: Can those three users give me back my post so I can provide the answer for other users to benefit from???

Comment: and dont forget the .h file. Please also post that. I see these mods do not want to clear my post so I can post my answer. Can you help me out so I can also accept your answer....

Comment: also I see some BLE tags are only 8bit and not 16bit, so there is still more to do in this library for the developers...

Comment: to cater for the 8bit tags can you post this as well: float val = oBeacon.getTemp();
unsigned int x = (unsigned int) val; int y = (int8_t) x;